# xmlns in intellij project are not recognized?

Tags: java, namespaces, xhtml, presentation

Currently I am working on a presentation layer for a software project in java. In the skeleton project we were provided with, there already were a bunch of namespaces included.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:ng="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

These are the ones that are included in almost every .xhtml file in the project. I have spent some time already sorting the maven dependencies out in the pom.xml file, but still the project can't seem to get the external resources. I have tried to invalidate the caches, but the urls are still displayed in red and when I try to display my page on a localhost, stuff like buttons and boxes are just not shown, just plain text.

What else could I try to get the project to recognize the external resources?

Appearantly its also only my intellij that can't handle the resources, one of my teammates could load everything just fine.